# Javascript Count click on link and store it in cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, hyperlink, counter

i'm newbee in javascript language and have a problem :

I have a script who count click on a link and display none this link when 20 clicks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var compteur=0;
    function submitOnce()
    {
    var i,h5s = document.getElementsByTagName('h5'), nbr = h5s.length;

    compteur +=1;
    if (compteur==20){
    for (i=0;i<nbr;i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("h5")[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("quota").style.display = "block";
    }
    };
    };
 </script>
```

Now, i if user navigate to other section of the web site, count is reset. So i would like to store the result of the count in cookie.

I found a script who describe the process to store number of visits of a web site in cookie.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  <!--
  function cherchevaleur()
  {
   var valeur = "";
   if(document.cookie)
   {
    valeurdepart = document.cookie.indexOf("=") + 1;
    valeurfin = document.cookie.indexOf(";");
    if(valeurfin == -1) valeurfin = document.cookie.length;
    valeur = document.cookie.substring(valeurdepart,valeurfin);
   }
   return valeur;
  }

  function fixervaleur(indic, valeur, expire)
  {
   var maintenant = new Date();
   var temps = new Date(maintenant.getTime() + expire);
   document.cookie = indic+"="+valeur+"; expires="+temps.toGMTString()+";";
  }

  function compteur()
  {
   var tpsexpire = 1000*60*60*24*1;
   var nombre = cherchevaleur();
   var compte = 0;
   if(nombre != "") compte = parseInt(nombre);
   if(document.cookie)
   {
    compte = compte + 1;
    fixervaleur("compte",compte,tpsexpire);
   }
   else
   {
    compte = 1;
    fixervaleur("compte",compte,tpsexpire);
   }
  alert("C'est votre " + compte + "ème visite sur cette page!");
  }
  //-->
 </script>
```

But i don't understand how to insert my count script. Is there someone who could help me to understand ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use these `Setcookies` and `Getcookies` function of JavaScript to read and write value in cookies...

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
            var exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value + "; path=/";
        }
        function getCookie(c_name) {
            var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
            for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
                x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
                y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
                x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
                if (x == c_name) {
                    return unescape(y);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thaks a lot for this fast answer ! It looks like more difficult... Can you give more information ? I'm really newbee.